# My CSS Body styles not applying to login page

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, visual-studio-2005

I'm having a stupid css issue I can't seem to figure out. Here is my simple .css file:

```
#divBody
{
    margin-left:25px;
}
#divTrans
{
    margin:15px;
}
Body
{
    background-color:Black;
}
```

I link this in my pages'  tag like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="BodyLayout.css" />
```

The 'Body' style applies to all the pages in my site except my login page.. (index.aspx). Here's the page's code in question:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="index.aspx.cs" Inherits="index" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="BodyLayout.css" />
  <title>Optoma USA - Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
  <div style="text-align:left; width:990px; height:780px; background-color:White;">
  <div id="divBody">
    <form id="form1" runat="server" target="_self">
<!--The rest isn't important, I don't think
```

When I inline the style, it works.. but not otherwise. Like I said, it works in all of my other pages. Anyone know why this is happening?

Here's my entire web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- 
    Note: As an alternative to hand editing this file you can use the 
    web admin tool to configure settings for your application. Use
    the Website->Asp.Net Configuration option in Visual Studio.
    A full list of settings and comments can be found in 
    machine.config.comments usually located in 
    \Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.x\Config 
-->
<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
  <!--**Settings added for AJAX-->
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
      <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
        <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
        <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
          <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
          <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
          <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
        </sectionGroup>
      </sectionGroup>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <!--**end added settings for AJAX-->
    <appSettings/>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="OptomaLoanerConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=OPTOSQL1;Initial Catalog=OptomaLoaner;User ID=sa;Password=tcnumberone" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
        <add name="MAS200RAWConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=OPTOSQL1;Initial Catalog=MAS200RAW;User ID=sa;Password=tcnumberone" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>
    <!--**settings added for AJAX-->
    <pages>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit"
             assembly="AjaxControlToolkit"/>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions,
          Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls"
             assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
             PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <!--**end added settings for AJAX-->
        <!-- 
            Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging 
            symbols into the compiled page. Because this 
            affects performance, set this value to true only 
            during development.
        -->
        <compilation debug="false">
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.DirectoryServices, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
                <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <!--**added assembly for AJAX-->
        <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <!--**end added assemblies for AJAX-->
      </assemblies>
        </compilation>
    <!--**added for AJAX-->
    <httpHandlers>
      <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
      <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </httpHandlers>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </httpModules>
    <!--**end added for AJAX-->
        <!--<authentication> mode:forms;-->
        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms loginUrl="~/index.aspx" name="adAuthCookie" path="/">
            </forms>
        </authentication>
        <!--<authorization>:-->
        <authorization>
            <!-- <deny>: will deny all users and redirect to login page,
            unless they are properly authenticated-->
            <deny users="?"/>
            <!--<allow>: might be configured later. probably will not need-->
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
        <!--<identity>: this might need to be set to true, and a default anonymous
    account might have to be created in IIS at production time. refer to
    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180890%28v=vs.80%29.aspx
    for more information.-->
        <identity userName="CTX_DOMAIN\ldapweb" password="ldap327714" />
        <!--
            The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
            of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
            during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
            it enables developers to configure html error pages 
            to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.

        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
            <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
            <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
        </customErrors>
        -->
    </system.web>
  <!--*****added settings for AJAX-->
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules>
      <remove name="ScriptModule"/>
      <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler"
        type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
      <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory"/>
      <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices"/>
      <remove name="ScriptResource"/>
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add name="ScriptResource" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <!--*****end added settings for AJAX-->
</configuration>
```

Comment: I don't see divTrans in the snippet you provided.  It would be a lot easier to debug if we could see the actual page, could you provide a link?

Comment: divTrans ins't used in this page.

Comment: Is it because you are doing "Body" which isn't an element since you're doing XHTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem, mine was to do with permissions.

Your login page has to be public (so that people can access it) but you CSS script is probably in a protected folder or has permissions set to hide it.

See if putting your CSS in a public folder allows it to work.

**EDIT:**
Then it could be the individual file permissions in the web.config:

```
<location path="BodyLayout.css">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="?"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: As you can see in my <link> tag, the .css file is in the main directory. It should be in a folder lol, but yeah, its not at the moment.

Comment: Then it may be the file permissions set in the web.config See edit to my answer as there is better formatting available :)

Comment: I don't think permissions would hinder the CSS - it would simply reject you from seeing the ENTIRE page alltogether. If everything else is showing up (i.e. page elements) , it's something simpler than permissions

Comment: @Zakman411: I have to admit that asp.net is not my strong point, so you could well be correct. Changing the permissions solved my issue so I thought I'd contribute as a possible solution.

Comment: @Tony no worries brotha didn't mean to sound rude - just my experience with ASP in the past. I could be wrong as well

Comment: Hopefully we'll both find out when Nicklamort gets the answer :)

Comment: Yea, im on a mission. I think the problem is something messing up my page references. I'll let you know when I figure it out..

Comment: This was it. I need to specify access to certain resources..going to have to try this tomorrow. time to go home!

Comment: This was driving me crazy and this did the trick.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem very similar to the one mentioned by Tony, and I solved it by granting permissions to whole Content folder with `CSS` files in `web.config` file:

```
<location path="Content">
   <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?"/>
      </authorization>
   </system.web>
</location>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS `Body` tag doesn't match your `body` (lower case B) in the html. Use this:

```
body {

}
```

Comment: try swapping 'body' with *. That will apply the rule to everything - see if that works temporarily to make sure your CSS is actually connected correctly

Comment: LOL good idea. It didn't do anything. Guess it's not linking to this page.. all my other pages that link to this went totally black though. WTH is going on XD

Comment: interesting. All files are in the same directory? If this page is in the same directory as all of the other pages w/ the working CSS, it should work. Perhaps it is indeed a web.config issue, but that has never hindered my CSS before (it will simply reject you from seeing the page alltogether) so that's hard to believe..

Comment: Now this is weird. When I switch to design view in VS, the css is applying. But I run the program (local server, run w/o debugging), its not applying..

Comment: clear your cache on your browser? Refresh lol? That shouldn't happen. Now it sounds like a build issue. Possibly restart the local server?

Comment: BRO, I'm making more discoveries. I have an image on my page as well that has never displayed before, and I couldn't figure out why, just showed alternate text. When I log in my site, and then click the back button, the CSS and image appear! WTF is going on lmao. Something is messing up my references in this page, and when I click the back button on (or view page in design mode) it references fine..

Comment: Haha dude all I can say is "thank you, Microsoft." ASP is tricky - sometimes you simply have to restart the server and you'll never know exactly what happened lmao

Comment: @Nicklamort: When you say "When I log in my site, and then click the back button, the CSS and image appear!" that sounds like a permission problem to me. Can you post some (or all) of your web.config file?

Comment: omg, it does. If I click 'back' after logging, it all appears (my css and images). If I 'Logout' (and get redirected to the broken login page), nothing appears.. However, I posted all this to the server and it all worked fine. So, I guess its just local, which is good.. but still, wth? My web.config is posted